# @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) display to screen?

Tags: javascript, html, sitecore

I am using this for password take in:

`@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)` on my HTML page.

Somewhere I am having issues with taken in German Umlauts. I want to display this password on the screen after it gets submitted to see if the chars are coming in correctly. Somewhere my code is not properly using UTF8 and I want to see if it is possibly sending back the wrong chars right off the bat.

How do I display the password from that line on screen as an alert or call in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This will display the value of your Password field in the browser's Console (Hit `F12`) when the Password field loses focus:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('Password').addEventListener('blur',writeVal,false);

    function writeVal(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('Password').value);
    }
</script
```

Comment: thanks. I need to call this though after I hit submit. I need to see if my application is grabbing the right char code. Just displaying the password as it is written in the password box will not help me much.

Comment: I would need to see the server-side method you are posting to in that case.

Comment: [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

Comment: That appears to be your model's Password property. I am looking for the Controller method you are posting to.